# Open multiple files in new tabs as read only

Tags: multiple-files, tabbed-user-interface

I would like to open new tabs for each file matching an expression, each file in a new tab and as read only. I do not want to replace my current buffer, just append the new tabs.

This comes very close, but unfortunately it replaces any existing tabs:

```
command OpenLogs args X:\Path\ToLogs\*Log.txt | tab all | tabdo set readonly
```

Any ideas?

Comment: With *"replaces any existing data"* I assume you mean *"Replaces all the existing tabs*? See: [How can I open multiple tabs at once?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2108/51) for an explanation on why this happens, and a way to fix it.

Comment: Yeah that's right, any existing tab/tabs/buffers disappears running the above. I saw that for loop of yours earlier but was hoping it can be accomplished without writing a function. Perhaps that's not possible.

Comment: You can put the code in a single line, if you want... `for f in glob(..) | execute ... | setlocal readonly | endfor` ... I don't see the problems with creating a function, though, as it's more readable.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using the entire function for readability. It's not too much code after all!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using Carpetsmoker's solution here: [How can I open multiple tabs at once?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2108/51), simply replacing

```
execute 'tabedit ' . l:c
```

with

```
execute 'tabedit ' . l:c . '| setlocal readonly'
```

Comment: [Here is an expanded version](https://gist.github.com/Carpetsmoker/1d9eda4d66daed954176) of the function which allows you to pass an expression; use it like: `:call OpenMultipleTabs(['/var/log/*'], 'setlocal readonly')` ...

Comment: That last one did not work for me. They are opened in tabs but readonly is not set.