# Open multiple files using ex command :edit and a wildcard

Tags: multiple-files

Is it possible to load multiple files at the same using :edit? I tried:

```
:e ~/dev/myproject/*.c
```

and it did not work.

(Note this is different than "How to open multiple files matching a wildcard expression?" because in that question he is not using :edit)

Comment: But the answer is the same -- `:edit` doesn't take more than one argument, so use one of the commands that does.

Comment: @jamessan I do not want to give multiple args, I want to use ONE argument which is a wildcard.

Comment: Yes, and that _one_ argument is expanded to _multiple_ filenames, which `:edit` doesn't not accept.  `:edit` only accepts a single filename, so use a command which supports multiple filenames.

Comment: If your wildcard does only expand to a single filename, you can simply use your command given, e.g. `:e *.txt`, however Vim will complain, if this expands to more than one file. So you can e.g. use `:argadd *.txt|:next` or similar.

Comment: Another related question: [How can I open multiple tabs at once?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2108/51)