# Is there a way to use a wildcard with :tabnew

Tags: tabbed-user-interface

I often find myself wanting to open multiple tabs at the same time from within vim.

I would like something like this:

```
:tabnew src/Class.*
```

which would open all matching files in separate tabs. Is there a way to get this functionality?

Comment: Try this: `:call map(glob('src/Class.*', 0, 1), {_,v -> execute('tabnew '..fnameescape(v))})`.  You could turn it into a custom `:Tabnew` command: `:com -bar -nargs=1 Tabnew call map(glob(<q-args>, 0, 1), {_,v -> execute('tabnew '..fnameescape(v))})`. To use it, you would execute: `:Tabnew src/Class.*`. See also [How can I open multiple tabs at once?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2108/how-can-i-open-multiple-tabs-at-once/2110#2110).

Answer (score 2):

To open a bunch of files you can use `:h :args` and `:h :all`. That is, to open all `Class.*` files (and only such files!) in the current tab you can do just `args Class.* | all` (or `args Class.* | tab all` to open each file in a new tab).

It requires a bit more work if you want to keep all opened windows/tabs intact and to preserve the global arglist. The target command can be defined like that:

```
command! -bar -nargs=+ -complete=file Tabedit tabnew | arglocal |
    \ args <args> | silent execute 'argdo tabedit' | tabclose
```

Now `Tabedit Class.*` should do the job.