# How can I modify OpenMultipleTabs so that I can open buffers for new files?

Tags: tabbed-user-interface, filesystem, multiple-files

When [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60818926/430766) for a command to enable me to open multiple tabs in normal mode, I [found](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2110/852) a custom command to do this:

```
" Open multiple tabs at once
fun! OpenMultipleTabs(pattern_list)
    for p in a:pattern_list
        for c in glob(l:p, 0, 1)
            execute 'tabedit ' . l:c
        endfor
    endfor
endfun

command! -bar -bang -nargs=+ -complete=file Tabedit call OpenMultipleTabs([<f-args>])

" less typing:
map <C-n> :Multitab
```

**However**, this doesn't work when trying to open a path that doesn't exist yet. So one cannot use this to create new files. Example:

```
:Tabedit *.c
" works: opens all matching .c files
:!touch existing-file.txt
:Tabedit existing-file.txt
" works: opens the existing file
:Tabedit new-file.txt
" doesn't do anything at all
```

**So what I want is for strings that don't require expansion, to open the same as with `:tabedit`.**

Answer (score 1):

My crude solution is to test whether `glob` finds any files and otherwise just to open the expression previously passed to `glob`. There is probably a more elegant way to do this.

```
fun! OpenMultipleTabs(pattern_list)
    for p in a:pattern_list
        let gl = glob(l:p, 0, 1)
        if empty(gl)
            let gl = [ l:p ]
        endif
        for c in gl
            execute 'tabedit ' . l:c
        endfor
    endfor
endfun
```

Comment: Won't this fail if you pass `*.c` and there are no C files...i.e. try to open single file `*.c`? Might be better to test the pattern for wildcards. If none, open using name as is otherwise use `glob()`. Question is whether there's a portable, robust way to test for wildcards. (You could simply look for for `*`, `?`, `**` but what about escaped wildcards? Or system specific wildcards?)

Comment: @BLayer Yes, I realise that. It just opens `*.c` as a file name. This is likely not intended, but I can live with it. And as you say, you'd need to have a portable way to test for wildcards, which I'm not keen on jury rigging myself.

Comment: If it's just a personal script and you're using it on *nix I'd go the wildcard match route. It should be less error-prone than the current version. Pattern is just something like `[^\\]\(?\|*\|\[[^]]*]\)`. If you don't use `[abc]` wildcards then you just need `[^\\]\(?\|*\)` and that'll work on Windows, too. Your vim, your decision, though.